# R: integer versus numeric

Tags: r

This question perhaps has been answered earlier, but I did not see an answer.

I have a data set that consists of numbers and missing values.  One row is a percentage.  Below is a small set of fake data where AA, BB and CC are the column names.  The third row in this data set is the percentage.

```
   AA    BB    CC
  234   432    78
 1980  3452  2323
 91.1    90  93.3
   34   123    45
```

In this case, when I read the data set AA and CC are numeric and BB is integer.  I guess somewhere 90.0 was rounded to 90.  If I do not specify that BB is numeric could this cause problems with basic arithmetic?

I believe that if dd = 1 and ee = 2 and both are integer then the C language says dd / ee = 0, while R says dd / ee = 0.5.

Below is a series of simple mathematical operations that all seem to suggest answers in R are not changed regardless of whether the data are numeric or integer.  Nevertheless, I keep thinking that it would be smart to specify that all variables are numeric when reading the data.  Using Google I have found an example or two where the data type did seem to make a difference, but not below.

```
aa <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
bb <- 2
str(aa)
str(bb)

cc <- as.integer(aa)
dd <- as.integer(bb)
str(cc)
str(dd)

aa/bb
cc/dd
aa/dd
cc/bb

ee <- aa * aa
str(ee)
sum(ee/2)

ff <- cc * cc
str(ff)
sum(ff/2)

gg <- 4.14

hh <- ((aa * aa) * gg) / 2
hh
ii <- ((cc * cc) * gg) / 2
ii

jj <- (aa * aa) / gg
jj
kk <- (cc * cc) / gg
kk
jj == kk

mm <- as.integer(1)
nn <- as.integer(2)
mm/nn
```

I guess I am hoping for reassurance that this is not likely an issue with simple math, but I suspect it can.  I keep thinking there is a fundamental rule of programming here, but I am not sure what that is.  (I am aware of the concept of double precision.)

Thanks for any advice with what is surely a basic issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Division using the `/` operator will always return a "numeric", i.e. the equivalent of a C "double". The numerators and denominators are first coerced to numeric and then the division is done. If you want to use integer division you can use `%/%`. If you want to create an integer then you can use `trunc` or `floor` or you can use `round(x , 0)` or you can use as.integer. The first second and fourth of those options are equivalent. The round function will still return "numeric" even though the printed representation appears integer.  I do not think you need to worry as long as you will be happy with "double"/"numeric" results. Heck, we even allow division by 0.

Your 'aa' variable was classed as "numeric" despite being entered as a bunch of integers but had you used:

```
aa <- 1:8  # sequences are integer class.
```

It sounds as though you will not be too surprised by [FAQ 7.31](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f)